# AngularJS custom filter don't receive data

Tags: angularjs, filter

**I have a problem with a new filter which don't receive the data:**

here my error log:

[image]

Controller Code:

```
angular.module('reklaApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, Reklas, Modal) {

$scope.newRekla = {};

Reklas.getAll()
  .success(function(data) {
    $scope.reklas = data;
  });
```

Filter Code:

```
angular.module('reklaApp')
.filter('dateFilter', function () {
return function (items) {
    var filtered = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

        var item = items[i];

        filtered.push(item);

    }

    return filtered;
};
});
```

HTML Code:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="rekla in reklas | dateFilter">
      <td>{{rekla.dt | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</td>
      <td>{{rekla.order}}</td>
      <td>{{rekla.personal}}</td>
      <td>{{rekla.department}}</td>
      <td>{{rekla.xyz}}</td>
      <td>{{rekla.desc | limitTo: '50'}}</td>
      <td>{{rekla.costs}}</td>
```

I think the "item" variable dont receive the data from the ng-repeat!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you didn't create it to begin with on your $scope. So since your getAll function takes some time the filter doesn't have the data. You can fix this two ways:

By first initializing the variable:

```
angular.module('reklaApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, Reklas, Modal) {

    $scope.newRekla = {};
    $scope.reklas = [];

    Reklas.getAll()
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.reklas = data;
      });
```

Or by updating your filter:

```
angular.module('reklaApp')
    .filter('dateFilter', function () {
    return function (items) {
        if(!angular.isArray(items)){ return items }
        var filtered = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

            var item = items[i];

            filtered.push(item);

        }

        return filtered;
    };
    });
```